# How do web scrape more underlying data from a websites map location?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Currently, I have successfully used python to scrape data from a competitor's website to find out store information. The website has a map where you can enter a zip code and it will tell you all the stores in the area of a my current location. The website sends a GET request to pull store data by using this link:

https://www.homedepot.com/StoreSearchServices/v2/storesearch?address=37028&radius=50&pagesize=30

My goal is to scrape all store information not just the imaginary zip code = 12345 & pagesize=30.
How should I go about getting all the store information? Would it be better to iterate through a dataset of zip codes to pull all the stores or is there a better way to do this? I've tried expanding past 30 page size but it looks like that is the limit on the request.

Comment: your link gives me message `Not Found`

Comment: https://www.homedepot.com/StoreSearchServices/v2/storesearch?address=37028&radius=50&pagesize=30

Comment: do whatever you like. Probably it would be faster and easier to get it as JSON from your link. And if you need it only once then it may not makes problem. Maybe if you get problem with this method then you will think how to do it in different way.

Comment: So I got the JSON from the link, however, the max stores per link per zip code is 30 stores. Is it better to iterate through all zip codes or is there a better way to do this? Unfortunately, large amount of zip codes will have the same stores.

Comment: I can get even `pagesize=40` - but I have to change range to get so many place. Response has `"currentPage":1` - so maybe it can load next `40` results if you add some parameter - maybe `page=` or `offert=`. Maybe you should use `DevTools` in `Chrome`/`Firefox` (tab `Network`) to see what page use when you visit next pages in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This url gives JSON with `"currentPage":1` which can means it can use some kind of pagination.

I added `&page=2` and it seems it works

Page 1:

https://www.homedepot.com/StoreSearchServices/v2/storesearch?address=37028&radius=250&pagesize=40&page=1

Page 2:

https://www.homedepot.com/StoreSearchServices/v2/storesearch?address=37028&radius=250&pagesize=40&page=2

Page 3:

https://www.homedepot.com/StoreSearchServices/v2/storesearch?address=37028&radius=250&pagesize=40&page=3

For test I use bigger `range=250` to get JSON with `"recordCount":123`

I found that it works also with `pagesize=40`.
For bigger value it sends JSON with error message.

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working code:

Page blocks request without `User-Agent`

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0',
}

url = 'https://www.homedepot.com/StoreSearchServices/v2/storesearch'

payload = {
    'address': 37028,
    'radius': 250,
    'pagesize': 40,
    'page': 1,
}

page = 0

while True:

    page += 1
    print('--- page:', page, '---')
    
    payload['page'] = page
    response = requests.get(url, params=payload, headers=headers)
    
    data = response.json()

    print(data['searchReport'])
                        
    if "stores" not in data:
        break
    
    for number, item in enumerate(data['stores'], 1):
        print(f'{number:2} | phone: {item["phone"]} | zip: {item["address"]["postalCode"]}')
```

Result:

```
--- page: 1 ---
{'recordCount': 123, 'currentPage': 1, 'storesPerPage': 40}
 1 | phone: (931)906-2655 | zip: 37040
 2 | phone: (270)442-0817 | zip: 42001
 3 | phone: (615)662-7600 | zip: 37221
 4 | phone: (615)865-9600 | zip: 37115
 5 | phone: (615)228-3317 | zip: 37216
 6 | phone: (615)269-7800 | zip: 37204
 7 | phone: (615)824-2391 | zip: 37075
 8 | phone: (615)370-0730 | zip: 37027
 9 | phone: (615)889-7211 | zip: 37076
10 | phone: (615)599-4578 | zip: 37064

etc. 

--- page: 2 ---
{'recordCount': 123, 'currentPage': 2, 'storesPerPage': 40}
 1 | phone: (662)890-9470 | zip: 38654
 2 | phone: (502)964-1845 | zip: 40219
 3 | phone: (812)941-9641 | zip: 47150
 4 | phone: (812)282-0470 | zip: 47129
 5 | phone: (662)349-6080 | zip: 38637
 6 | phone: (502)899-3706 | zip: 40207
 7 | phone: (662)840-8390 | zip: 38866
 8 | phone: (502)491-3682 | zip: 40220
 9 | phone: (870)268-0619 | zip: 72404
10 | phone: (256)575-2100 | zip: 35768

etc.
```

---

If you want to keep as `DataFrame` then maybe first put all items on list and later convert this list to `DataFrame`

```
# --- before loop ----

all_items = []

page = 0

# --- loop ----

while True:

    # ... code ...
    
    for number, item in enumerate(data['stores'], 1):
        print(f'{number:2} | phone: {item["phone"]} | zip: {item["address"]["postalCode"]}')
        all_items.append(item)

# --- after loop ----

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(all_items)

print(df)
```

Because JSON keep `address` as directory `{'postCode': ... , ...}` so some columns may have it as directory

```
print(df.iloc[0])
```

```
storeId                                                             0726
name                                                     Clarksville, TN
phone                                                      (931)906-2655
address                {'postalCode': '37040', 'county': 'Montgomery'...
coordinates                        {'lat': 36.581677, 'lng': -87.300826}
services               {'loadNGo': True, 'propane': True, 'toolRental...
storeContacts                 [{'name': 'Brenda G.', 'role': 'Manager'}]
storeHours             {'monday': {'open': '6:00', 'close': '21:00'},...
url                           /l/Clarksville-TN/TN/Clarksville/37040/726
distance                                                       32.530296
proDeskPhone                                               (931)920-9400
flags                  {'bopisFlag': True, 'assemblyFlag': True, 'bos...
marketNbr                                                           0019
axGeoCode                                                             00
storeTimeZone                                                    CST6CDT
curbsidePickupHours    {'monday': {'open': '09:00', 'close': '18:00'}...
storeOpenDt                                                   1998-08-13
storeType                                                         retail
toolRentalPhone                                                      NaN
```

See: `{ }` in `address`, `services`, `storeHours`,etc

It may need also to convert it to separated rows.

```
df['address'].apply(pd.Series)
```

and concat it with original `df`

```
df2 = pd.concat( [df, df['address'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1 )
```

The same way you may do with other columns.

Comment: I added minimal working code.

Comment: Do you know how to then convert that to a pandas df? I tried using df = pd.DataFrame(items) and I keep getting an error.

Comment: maybe first append every item (from every pages) to normal list and later convert this list to `DataFrame`.  And if you have nested values like `item["address"]["postalCode"]` then convert it (manually) to normal `item["address_postalCode"]` or `item["postalCode"]` because `DataFrame` is normal 2D table, without nested elements.

Comment: I added example how to keep it as DataFrame - but frankly, this is new problem and you should rather ask on new page. You would have place to show full error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before and you stated one of the solutions,

I recommend searching the domain/sitemap.xml and domain/robots.txt for the available stores.

also sometimes the data is stored in the .js requests so open the network tab and search for one of the stores' id.